# Java socket writeObject stucks

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to create some local chat software.
Everything is working fine but just sticks on one point;
when a user clicks on a button my program gets stuck.

I wrote a modified class which behaves for both the server and the client.

Below is my code:

```
package connections;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import ui.ChatWindow;

public class Chat{

private SocketChannel socketChannel;
private ConnectionType connectionType;

private ObjectOutputStream out;
private ObjectInputStream in;

private String strClientName;

private ChatWindow chatWindow;
private String strMessage;

public Chat(SocketChannel socketChannel, ConnectionType connectionType) {
    this.socketChannel = socketChannel;
    this.connectionType = connectionType;

    init();
}

private void init() {

    new Thread(this::initThread).start();
}

private void initThread() {
    try {
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(socketChannel.socket().getOutputStream());
        in = new ObjectInputStream(socketChannel.socket().getInputStream());

        if (connectionType == ConnectionType.SERVER) {
            getClientName();
            sendMyName();
        } else {
            sendMyName();
            getClientName();
        }

        chatWindow = new ChatWindow();
        chatWindow.btnSend.addActionListener(this::eventBtnSend);
        chatWindow.setTitle(strClientName);
        chatWindow.setSize(600, 400);
        chatWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        if (connectionType == ConnectionType.CLIENT) {
            chatWindow.setVisible(true);
            chatWindow.requestFocus();
        }

        System.out.println("here");

        beginChat();

        System.out.println("thread ends");

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Chat.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

private void getClientName() {

    try {
        strClientName = (String) in.readObject();
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Status.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

private void sendMyName() {

    try {
        out.writeObject(main.Config.myName);
        out.flush();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Status.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

private void beginChat() {
    while (true) {
        try {                
            waitForMessage();
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Chat.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}

private void waitForMessage() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    System.out.println("waiting for Message : " + connectionType);
    strMessage = (String) in.readObject();
    System.out.println("Message received");
    chatWindow.txtDisplay.append(strClientName + " : " + strMessage + "\n");

    if(chatWindow.isVisible() == false){
        chatWindow.setVisible(true);
    }
}

private void sendMessage(String strMessage) {

    try {
        out.writeObject(strMessage);
        out.flush();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Chat.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

private void eventBtnSend(ActionEvent ae){
    System.out.println("a");
    sendMessage(chatWindow.txtMessage.getText());
    System.out.println("b");
    chatWindow.txtDisplay.append("Me : " + chatWindow.txtMessage.getText() + "\n");
    System.out.println("c");
    chatWindow.txtMessage.setText("");
}
}
```

When the server and client connects I can see this output:

```
here
waiting for Message : SERVER
here
waiting for Message : CLIENT
```

But when I click on the send button my program becomes stuck. 
After clicking the button I can see:

```
a on console.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The english has been improved for you so that the question is more readable. You might want to simplify the program to focus on just the part with the error, rather than include the whole thing in your question. There is some information on this in the [SO help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This way you can get better answers from more people.

Comment: The code would be more clean if you created a server and client class instead of if/else.If your program gets stuck perhaps you should check the status of threads in program using Jconsole

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word is 'blocks'. It's blocking I/O. It blocks.

Don't perform blocking operations on the event thread. All the networking code should run on separate threads. That includes `readObject()` and `writeObject(),` and `flush(),` and creating the streams too.

Comment: i dont know why but, i changed serversocketchannel by serversocket and socketchannel by socket , it solved my problem, what is wrong? what am i missing in nio. please tell me i really want to know

Comment: The explanation is that the streams returned by `channels.socket()` appear to have undocumented internal synchronization, so that you can't read and write at the same time. You would have had one thread blocking in read, which would have prevented the write from executing. But you're only using NIO to create the channels. From there you're using streams. So, why *not* use `ServerSocket` and `Socket?` There streams don't have the internal synchronziation.